# Polymer 1.0 more-routing

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

**Polymer: 1.0.3** 
**More routing: 1.0.0**

Having some issues with Polymer "more-routing". Those are -

1) Get this log on console -

```
[dom-bind::_annotatedComputationEffect]: compute method `urlFor` not defined
```

2) First level routing works (even though I get those error/warning messages). But second level routing (i mean nested routing) does not work. On "users" page pressing the name doesn't take me to "user-info" page. In fact the name does not appear as a link, it appears as a text. Here is my code -

My "routing.html"--

```html
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/more-routing/more-routing.html">

<more-routing-config driver="hash"></more-routing-config>


<more-route name="home" path="/"></more-route>

<more-route name="users" path="/users">
  <more-route name="user-info" path="/:name"></more-route>
</more-route>

<more-route name="contact" path="/contact"></more-route>
```

My "index.html" ---

```html
    <more-route-selector>
        <paper-menu class="list" on-iron-select="onMenuSelect">
            <a route="home" href="{{urlFor('home')}}">
                <iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon>
                <span>Home</span>
            </a>


            <a route="users" href="{{urlFor('users')}}">
                <iron-icon icon="info"></iron-icon>
                <span>Users</span>
            </a>

            <a route="contact" href="{{urlFor('contact')}}">
                <iron-icon icon="mail"></iron-icon>
                <span>Contact</span>
            </a>
        </paper-menu>
    </more-route-selector>
    <more-route-selector selectedParams="{{params}}">
        <iron-pages>
            <section route="home">
                <paper-material elevation="1">
                    <bortini-home></bortini-home>
                </paper-material>
            </section>

            <section route="users">
                <paper-material elevation="1">
                    <h2 class="paper-font-display2">Users</h2>

                    <p>This is the users section</p>
                    <a href="{{urlFor('user-info', {name: 'Rob'})}}">Rob</a>
                </paper-material>
            </section>

            <section route="user-info">
                <paper-material elevation="1">
                    <h2 class="paper-font-display2">
                        User:<span>{{params.name}}</span>
                    </h2>

                    <div>This is <span>{{params.name}}</span>'s section</div>
                </paper-material>
            </section>

            <section route="contact">
                <paper-material elevation="1">
                    <h2 class="paper-font-display2">Contact</h2>

                    <p>This is the contact section</p>
                </paper-material>
            </section>
        </iron-pages>
    </more-route-selector>
```

Comment: You import the `more-routing` folder after you've imported the HTML file.  I don't know what this would do, exactly, but I'm betting it shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Zikes: Not sure what you mean, but on my "elements.html" I have moved import of "routes.html" before importing my html pages. But still the same

Comment: In the first code block you import `more-routing/more-routing.html` and then you import `more-routing/`. The second one should probably be removed, and may be causing unexpected behaviors.

Comment: @Zikes: Yes that was a typo. I removed that, and that solved one of my problem. But other or the main problem remains though. Nested routing is not working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 1.0 (perhaps earlier), Polymer stopped supporting expressions inside data-bindings ([Migration Guide - Data binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#data-binding)). Thankfully, you can still call a function in a binding (called a "[computed binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed)").

From what I can tell, the `urlFor()` method must be slightly too complex to work as a computed binding (the params object isn't a dependent property). I was able to make it work by wrapping `urlFor()` in a simpler function - one that works as a computed binding - something like this:

```
<more-routing-config driver="path"></more-routing-config>
<more-route name="users" path="/users">
  <more-route name="user-info" path="/:name"></more-route>
</more-route>

<template is="dom-bind">
  <a href="{{makeUrl('user-info', 'Rob')}}">Rob</a>
</template>

<script>
  var template = document.querySelector('template');
  template.makeUrl = function(route, name) {
    return MoreRouting.urlFor(route, {name:name});
  };
</script>
```

You can also pass variables in your computed binding, as long as they're dependent properties, like the `item` in a repeating template

```
<template is="dom-bind">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{users}}">
    <a href="{{makeUrl('user-info', item)}}">{{item.name}}</a>
  </template>
</template>

<script>
  var template = document.querySelector('template');
  template.makeUrl = function(route, user) {
    return MoreRouting.urlFor(route, {name:user.name});
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Yes I know that it works like the way you mentioned. But still that wouldn't take away the error printing on the console.

Comment: It works perfectly __while making a URL__. But the selectedParams is not accessible in the `<section>`s as mentioned in its demo video